# Transfer Date header removed from Camel DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I was try to hit REST API with authorization from two header fileds: Authorization and Date but Date field has removed from DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy. I was try to replace it with mine filter and set it into Jetty client, but Date header still missing into RequestProcessor and RestProcessor. I need to can transfer this header globally for all our requests. Here is a parts of my code.

```
@Component
public class RestAPIClientRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
    
        JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = camelContext.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
        jettyComponent.setHeaderFilterStrategy(new HeaderFilter());
        
        restConfiguration().component("jetty").scheme("http").port(80).host("localhost");    


        interceptSendToEndpoint("rest:post:*").process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) {

                Properties authProperties = CryptoUtil.duoAuthRequestEncode( duoConfig,"POST", exchange);

                Message msg = exchange.getMessage();
                msg.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authProperties.getProperty("auth"));
                msg.setHeader("Date", authProperties.getProperty("timestamp"));

            }
        });
        
        rest("/rest")
                .post("/accounts/v1/account/list")
                .to("direct:hello");

        from("direct:hello")
            .process(new RequestProcessor());

        from("timer:rest-client?period=60s")
            .to("direct:accountList");
        
        from("direct:accountList")
            .to("rest:post:/rest/accounts/v1/account/list")
            .process(new RestProcessor());
        
    }

}


@Component
public class HeaderFilter implements HeaderFilterStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean applyFilterToCamelHeaders(String headerName, Object headerValue, Exchange exchange) {

        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilterToExternalHeaders(String headerName, Object headerValue, Exchange exchange) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is coming from the REST component. He set HeaderFilter which override the other setted filter in HTTP component. REST component can not set HeaderFilterStrategy and always use default one. I was start to use only http component with setted mine customised filter instead rest and now can transfer deleted headers from DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy.

I replace it

```
   .to("rest:post:/rest/accounts/v1/account/list")
```

with

```
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant(urlQuery))
   .to("https://host.domain.com/rest/accounts/v1/account/list")
```